# Move one subplot down

Tags: matplotlib, subplot, colorbar, multiple-axes

I am making a 4 panel plot and was wondering if there is any way to just move the subplot in the bottom left down a bit so it stays in line with the rest of the plots and the titles don't overlay. I believe it is because the bottom left plot doesn't have a colorbar but I'm not sure how I would fix that. I am using the add subplot function. So for the bottom left pot the axes looks like this. `ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3,projection=proj)` [image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it might work to read the current position with `ax.get_position()`, then move it down a bit with `ax.set_position()`. Something like this:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

pos = axs[1, 0].get_position()
new_pos = [pos.x0, pos.y0-0.1, pos.width, pos.height]
axs[1, 0].set_position(new_pos)
```

This results in:

[image: The output of this code]

As for 'how much?'... Not sure if there's a better way than trial and error though. Not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`inset_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes) in combination with [`constrained` layout](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html?highlight=constrained):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, layout='constrained')
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flat):
    pcm = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random((20, 20)) * (i + 1))
    ax.set_title("very long title\nthat strechtes over two lines")
    if i != 2:
        cax = ax.inset_axes([0, -0.35, 1, 0.1])
        fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=ax, cax=cax, orientation='horizontal')
```

[image]

See also [Placing Colorbars](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html).